# Why is an error occurring after hosting a JSON Object Request?

Tags: java, android, json

I am hosting a very simple JSON Object Request through the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RequestQueue queue;
    String url = "https://www.google.com";
    String apiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
    String getApiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                getApiUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    Log.d("url", "onCreate: " + response.getString("title"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("url", "There was an error");
            }
        });
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);



    }

}
```

The point of this code is to just fetch the title attribute in the JSON Object of this URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

In my Manifest, I've included permission to the Internet and in my build.gradle, included the dependency for volley.

Logcat doesn't show any fatal errors either. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: could you put a log.d("tag","msg"+e) inside catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace()  } . The issue is probably there

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I have figured out a solution to my problem. Issue was that the min sdk version in my build.gradle was 30 and was compiling at 30 whereas my emulator had an API level of 29.

Comment: OMG on this solution even google developers won't be able to help you....  LOL .. Bcoz that was you internal issue and no one was familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code its perfectly working fine !!! Instead of Log.d() use Log.e() So the data in red color would be more visible to you :)

[image]

Comment: How, though? I ran it again, this time with log.e still getting same error. It prints out the error message "There was an error."  so it seems it went into `onErrorResponse`. I'll include a picture in my post. Is there any permissions you added or things you did before copying the code(other than internet permission/dependency)? Thanks.

Comment: The code `Log.d("url", "There was an error");` is WORSE THAN USELESS!  You need to know the error message itself and, ideally, a stack traceback.  Q: Could `VolleyError error` contain useful information you want to print out?